# Как получить значение XML_ID у пользовательского свойства?

Tags: битрикс

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить значение XML_ID у пользовательского свойства?

Я создал инфоблок, дальше в нем создаю разделы, поскольку эти разделы будут хранить не только элементы но еще и определенные значения появилась необходимость создать новое пользовательское поле которое хранит некие значения, с помощью приведенного кода ниже получилось получить ID значений списка. А, как получить значение XML_ID?

[Раньше был похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/110543/cms-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-xml_id), но там вопрос относился к инфоблокам, а тут пользовательское свойство.

```
CModule::IncludeModule('iblock');
    $arSelect = Array('ID', 'NAME', 'UF_TF');
    $arFilter = Array('IBLOCK_ID'=>$iblock, 'ACTIVE'=>'Y', 'GLOBAL_ACTIVE'=>'Y');
    $res = CIBlockSection::GetList(Array('SORT'=>'ASC'), $arFilter, true, $arSelect);

    while($ob = $res->GetNext()) {
?>
    <div>
        <?=$ob['UF_TF'] ?>
    </div>
<?}?>
```

Во вложении скрины, может помогут в понимании вопроса.
Заранее всем благодарен.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Друзья, и вновь получил ответ от тех.поддержки, комментирую если кому-то вдруг случайно пригодиться:

Получить можно таким образом:

```
Cmodule::IncludeModule('iblock');
$rsEnum = CUserFieldEnum::GetList(array(), array("ID" =>$ID));//$ID - id значения пользовательского поля типа список
$arEnum = $rsEnum->GetNext();
echo $arEnum["XML_ID"];
```

В моем случае это вот так выглядит:

```
<?
if(isset($_GET["ID"]){
    $newID = $_GET["ID"];
}

CModule::IncludeModule('iblock');
    $arSelect = Array('ID', 'NAME', 'UF_TF');
    $arFilter = Array('IBLOCK_ID'=>$newID, 'ACTIVE'=>'Y', 'GLOBAL_ACTIVE'=>'Y');
    $res = CIBlockSection::GetList(Array('SORT'=>'ASC'), $arFilter, true, $arSelect);

    while($ob = $res->GetNext()) {
?>
    <div>
        <?
            Cmodule::IncludeModule('iblock');
            $rsEnum = CUserFieldEnum::GetList(array(), array("ID" =>$newID));
            $arEnum = $rsEnum->GetNext();
            echo $arEnum["XML_ID"]; 
        ?>
    </div>
<?}?>
```

Comment: а как фильтровать по XML_ID свойства
PROPERTY_TF.XML_ID = 158 не работает 

Comment: уууу... блин, не понял вопрос... что конкретно не получается?